# ruby http timeout for downloading images

Tags: ruby, image, http, get

How do you specify a longer timeout for ruby's `http.get`?

Here's the context:

```
def downloadImage(domain, source, dest)
  # e.g. domain: "static.flickr.com"
  #      source: "/00/md5hashcode.jpg"

  puts("Downloading: #{domain}#{source}")

  Net::HTTP.start(domain) { |http|
    resp = http.get(source)
    open(dest, "wb") { |file|
      file.write(resp.body)
     }
  }
end
```

My requests keep timing out, what's the solution/workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the read_timeout method, in seconds. Example:

```
http.read_timeout = 500
```

Comment: That looks relevant! Where does it go? I tried putting it right before the line: `resp = http.get(source)`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Ah, actually, I think I have a different error. This should work. Thanks.